# Converge almost surely

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Consider the sequence of random variable$X_1,X_2...$ given by
$$X_n= \exp(-n^2(Z-\frac{1}{n})), n=1,2...$$
where $Z$ is uniformly ditributed random variable on the interval$[0,1]$. Does this sequence converge almost surely? If so, to what random variable?

I think that as $n\rightarrow\infty, Z$ will be mostly larger than $\frac{1}{n}$. So $\exp(-n^2(Z-\frac{1}{n}))$ will go to $\exp(-\infty)=0$. Am I correct?

Comment: "$Z$ will be mostly larger than $\frac{1}{n}$" - what do you mean by "mostly"? Basically, your idea is correct, but you should write this up more formally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, ignoring $\omega$ such that $Z \in (-\infty,0] \cup [1,\infty)$ (which has measure zero), there exists $N$ such that $Z(\omega)-\frac{1}{n}>0$ for all $n>N$ since $Z(\omega>0)$. Thus, $-n^2 (Z(\omega) - 1/n)  \to -\infty$ and thns, $X_n (\omega) \to 0$.